# how should I keep track of a detailViewController from a changing masterViewController?

Tags: ios, ipad, uistoryboard, segue

**Update** - I think I figured it out but please read my question if you'd like and check that my solution (in answers) is correct, thank you.

I'm new to the splitViewController and I'm having a hard time understanding how I should pop the detail view controller when the master is popped.

This may be hard for me to explain but I will try my best, here is a screenshot to understand my storyboard:
[image]

The MasterView is a NavigationController that has RootViewController of a TableView, when a user selects a cell the masterView pushes the next tableview and the detail is changed programmatically like so:

**In the initial root:**

```
  detailViewController = (CCGViewController *)[[self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject] topViewController];
```

**When a cell is clicked in root**

```
 [detailViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"replaceSearchWithSponsor" sender:self];
```

This is working to drill down but when I pop the Master View navigation controller I'd like to set up a good way to pop the detail views in their navigation stacks.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just subclassed UINavigationController and when I popped MasterNavigationController I popped the Detail as well. This seems to work for me, if you see any potential issues let me know:

in .h :

```
@interface CCGPopMasterNavigationController : UINavigationController

@end
```

in .m

```
@interface CCGPopMasterNavigationController ()

@end

@implementation CCGPopMasterNavigationController

- (UIViewController *)popViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated {
    [[[[self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject] topViewController]navigationController
      ] popViewControllerAnimated:animated];
    return [super popViewControllerAnimated:animated];
}
@end
```